# Back button double click

Tags: java, android

I am new android developer. I want to ask a question. Here is what I need: When the user click Back Button it counts as double click?

`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        --> what to write here?
    return;
    }
}`

Comment: Double click is not the usual android way of interacting with the user.  and this question is way too vague - i.e. it counts a a double click on what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check an interval between to presses and determine whether you it can be counted as a double click or not:

```
private static final long DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL = /* some value in ns. */;
private long lastPressTime;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long pressTime = System.nanoTime();
    if(pressTime - lastPressTime <= DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL) {
        // this is a double click event
    }
    lastPressTime = pressTime;
}
```

Comment: hmh.. this solution doesn't work.. maybe you didn't understand what I meant.. I have 2 activity and when on first activity is pressed the Search button.. shows the second activity with the list of strings.. but between them is progressDialog.. so when you click the back button on the second activity it shows progressDialog but not the first activity. To  show first activity users must click back button two times. So I wanted to do that when the user click back button on the second activity. The one click counts as a double click, and the users goes to first activity and not the progressDialog.

Comment: Yeah, seems I misunderstood your question. The progress dialog must be a part of the first activity if it's really a dialog. Just dismiss it when a user clicks the Search button.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably include the reasoning behind wanting this functionality in the question instead of a comment. It makes it a lot easier for us to point you in the right direction. There are a few ways to achieve what you want but I would not recommend the 'double back' method.

Instead, if you show the progress bar in a dialog or somewhere in the search activity, there is no activity between the search and the second activity. That way you do not need to do a double back.

Also, you could display the progress bar in the second activity until the work is done and then replace it with the actual content with another call to `setContentView(View)`. Note that this would require threading though (otherwise the progress bar would never show).

Answer (score 0):

Double Key Button

```
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```